# wglGetProcAddress for OpenGL 1.1 functions

Tags: windows, winapi, opengl

This wiki page on the OpenGL website claims that OpenGL 1.1 functions should NOT be loaded via `wglGetProcAddress()`, and the wording seems to imply that some systems will by design return `NULL` if you try:

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Platform_specifics:_Windows#wglGetProcAddress

(The idea being that only 1.2+ functions deserve loading by way of `wglGetProcAddress()`).

The page does not tell us who reported these failed `wglGetProcAddress()` calls on 1.1 functions, which I've never personally seen. And google searches so next to no information on the issue either.

Would `wglGetProcAddress()` actually return `NULL` for 1.1 functions for enough users such that I should actually care? Or does it just fail for a select few unlucky users with really broken GPU drivers (in which case I don't much care).

Has anybody else come across this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I technically answered this on the [discussion page of that Wiki article](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Talk%3aPlatform_specifics%3a_Windows), but:

> Would wglGetProcAddress() actually return NULL for 1.1 functions for enough users such that I should actually care?

It will return NULL for *all* users. I have tried it on NVIDIA and ATI platforms (recent drivers and DX10 hardware), and all of them do it.

Comment: I think my memory was just bad. The last time I played with OpenGL on Windows was like 2 years ago, must have been using GetProcAdress() straight up (which will of course work). My mistake.

Answer (score 3):

The question you should be asking yourself is whether it matters to you at all and whether you should care.

Loading the OpenGL 1.1 functions manually would mean that you have to use different function names, or they will collide with the declarations in `gl/gl.h`. Or, you must define `GL_NO_PROTOTYPES`, but in this case you will *also* not have OpenGL 1.0 functionality.
So, in any case, doing this would mean extra trouble for no gains, you can simply use 1.1 functionality without doing anything.

Having said that, I've tried this once because I thought it would be an ingenious idea to load *everything* dynamically (when I sobered up, I wondered what gave me that idea), and I can confirm that it does not (or at least, did not, 2 years ago) work with nVidia drivers.
Though, thinking about it, it's entirely justifiable, and even a good thing, that something that doesn't make sense doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, it does matter to me, and I should care.

And what do you mean by "... idea to load everything dynamically." What exactly is "everything" referring to there?

And no, I don't see how it's at all justifiable. You already have to load 1.2+ functions dynamically anyway, so any comprehensive function loader code you write based on the gl.spec file from the OpenGL registry is going to want to load 1.1 functions as well. Having to *stop* it from loading 1.1 calls feels like it deserves a good detailed technical explanation, and no matter how much I search the net I can't find one.

Comment: The technical explanation is that everything up to and including version 1.3 is considered "core, ubiquitous" and included in `gl.h`. Everything beyond version 1.3 has been considered as "extension, not certainly supported" for decades, and is in `glext.h`. Except under Windows, which for reasons that nobody but possibly someone at Microsoft could explain, also considers versions 1.2 and 1.3 functionality as "the unknown land".

Comment: About a comprehensive loader based on `gl.spec`, my best wishes for your endeavour. I have written such a thing, and can assure you that it's no fun at all (and unless you have a _very good_ reason, it isn't even a good idea considering that there is GLEW, which _just works_). Such a loader should of course only load what makes sense, instead of doing a lot of extra work to reimplement painfully what already works out of the box.

Comment: In case you're interested what my "very good" reasons for not just using GLEW were: I started programming on a computer with 16kB (an instruction table, pen and pencil, and Basic's POKE command being the development tools). The computer I learned C on some years later had 1MB which was more than anyone could ever imagine -- today, nobody cares about adding 50MB to a program. Yet, though I realize that it's silly, it still makes me go "WTF" if something as "trivial" as starting up requires me to add 300kB of library code. Thus, my loader is a 30kB DLL for full GL 3.3 which unloads after init.

Comment: "The technical explanation is that everything up to and including version 1.3 is considered "core, ubiquitous" and included in gl.h." This is not true at all. On Windows, `gl.h` only includes **1.1**.

Comment: @Damon: I started programming on a similar machine, and I don't care about adding a 300KB library if it means that I get done what I need to get done faster that way. Unless there is a specific need for that kind of frugality, it simply makes no sense in the modern world. It just means spending more time doing something that has already been done. My time is more valuable than 300KB. Now granted, I wrote my own OpenGL loader, but that was because GLEW has poor 3.x core support and I need that. But it wasn't because I needed to save a few KB.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: About Windows having only version 1.1 support, please read the comment carefully (the "except under Windows" bit), it is exactly what I'm saying. About writing one's own loader, as I've pointed out, there are very few valid reasons for most people to not just use GLEW. For me, 30k which will unload again after init instead of 300k for properly initializing a well-defined set of functionality with fallbacks (and, starting up in under 1ms) is dealmaker, even more so as 32-bit address space has become a limiting factor (mapping a large dataset) once before. Having spent 2 months ...

Comment: ... on writing a spec parser and code generator once was admittedly somewhat expensive, but nevertheless the code as it is now is optimal from my point of view (compliant, exactly what I need, nothing else, as well as lightweight, failsafe, and downgradeable). And, it'll work for any program that I write during the next years, so the cost will eventually amortize. (unless Khronos migrates the spec to XML, but this has not happened for years, so it's not likely to happen any time soon).